# MS CRM PCF Control Create Solution

Tags: msbuild, dynamics-crm, solution

I have a working PCF Control but cannot create the solution successfully:

I did

- create folder and jump in => FINE
- pac solution init -- ... => FINE
- pac solution add-reference -- => FINE
- msbuild /t:restore => FINE
- msbuild:

error : Ein Teil des Pfades "C:\Users\RobertHauptINFINITAS\Documents\kunden\r
epos\hansewerk-natur\CustomControls\PCF-Controls-All-v.2.1.5.0\CheckPhoneNumberControl\Solution\CC_CheckPhonenumb
er_V1\obj\Debug\Metadata\Controls\inf_BeBeControls.CheckPhoneNumberControl\css**CheckPhoneNumberControl.css**" konnt
e nicht gefunden werden. [C:\Users\RobertHauptINFINITAS\Documents\kunden\repos\hansewerk-natur\CustomControls\PCF
-Controls-All-v.2.1.5.0\CheckPhoneNumberControl\Solution\CC_CheckPhonenumber_V1\CC_CheckPhonenumber_V1.cdsproj]
Die Erstellung des Projekts "C:\Users\RobertHauptINFINITAS\Documents\kunden\repos\hansewerk-natur\CustomControls
PCF-Controls-All-v.2.1.5.0\CheckPhoneNumberControl\Solution\CC_CheckPhonenumber_V1\CC_CheckPhonenumber_V1.cdsproj
" ist abgeschlossen (Standardziele) -- FEHLER.

Fehler beim Buildvorgang.

"C:\Users\RobertHauptINFINITAS\Documents\kunden\repos\hansewerk-natur\CustomControls\PCF-Controls-All-v.2.1.5.0\C
heckPhoneNumberControl\Solution\CC_CheckPhonenumber_V1\CC_CheckPhonenumber_V1.cdsproj" (Standardziel) (1) ->
(ProcessCdsProjectReferencesOutputs Ziel) ->
C:\Users\RobertHauptINFINITAS.nuget\packages\microsoft.powerapps.msbuild.solution\1.16.6\build\Microsoft.Power
Apps.MSBuild.Solution.targets(102,5): error : Ein Teil des Pfades "C:\Users\RobertHauptINFINITAS\Documents\kunden
\repos\hansewerk-natur\CustomControls\PCF-Controls-All-v.2.1.5.0\CheckPhoneNumberControl\Solution\CC_CheckPhonenu
mber_V1\obj\Debug\Metadata\Controls\inf_BeBeControls.CheckPhoneNumberControl\css**CheckPhoneNumberControl.css**" kon
nte nicht gefunden werden. [C:\Users\RobertHauptINFINITAS\Documents\kunden\repos\hansewerk-natur\CustomControls\P
CF-Controls-All-v.2.1.5.0\CheckPhoneNumberControl\Solution\CC_CheckPhonenumber_V1\CC_CheckPhonenumber_V1.cdsproj]

```
0 Warnung(en)
1 Fehler
```

Translations:
Fehler = Error
konnte nicht gefunden werden = could not be found

File **CheckPhoneNumberControl.css** is in the control but it is not copied !?
Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance
Robert

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was changing the name of the folder that the custom control is stored in. So instead of PCF-Controls-All-v.2.1.5.0, you could try PCF-Controls-All-v.2.1.5.1 or something like that.